# How many natural $n$ with $\sigma(n)=0 \bmod{n}$ (where $\sigma$ is the sum-of-divisors function) are products of two distinct primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

> A natural number is called *unique* if $\sigma(n)=0 \bmod{n}$ where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of the positive divisors of $n$. How many unique natural numbers are there that are products of two distinct primes?

I have done the following:

From the Odd theorem, $\sigma(n)=2n$.

$n \mid \sigma(n)=2n$, so there are so many unique natural numbers as the Prime divisors of $n$ plus $1$.

Is this correct?

Comment: $\sigma(n)=2n$ is only true for perfect numbers, not all numbers. Could you clarify what you mean by the Odd theorem?

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=pq$ where $p \neq q$ are primes. The divisors of $n$ are $1,p,q,pq$. It follows that we have:
$$\sigma(n) = pq+p+q+1$$
And since $n \mid \sigma(n)$, we have:
$$pq \mid (pq+p+q+1)$$
As $p \mid (pq+p+q+1)$, it follows that $p \mid (q+1)$. Similarly, since $q \mid (pq+p+q+1)$, it follows that $q \mid (p+1)$. When $a \mid b$ for natural numbers $a$ and $b$, we can say that $a \leqslant b$. We then have $p \leqslant q+1$ and $q \leqslant p+1$. This can be written as $p-1 \leqslant q \leqslant p+1$.

Since $q \neq p$, we can see $q=p-1$ or $q=p+1$ i.e. $p$ and $q$ are consecutive primes. This is only possible if $(p,q)=(2,3),(3,2)$ and in either case, $n=pq=6$. Thus, $n=6$ is the only solution.

Comment: Yes, so what? ${}{}$